# sympy - integrate in 6-dimensional space

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, integral

I want to integrate the below formula with `sympy`.

[image: integral]

where `x` and `y` are 3-dimensional variables and the integration goes over the whole 3d-space. I don't know how to handle the double integral in sympy.

What I have done so far:
With the support of `sympy.vector` and `CoordSys3D`, integration of *one* vector is easy

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, ParametricRegion, vector_integrate
a,r,t,p = symbols('a,r,t,p', positive=True)
SPH=CoordSys3D('1', transformation='spherical', vector_names=list('rtp'), variable_names=list('RTP'))
f = exp(-a*SPH.R)
R3 = ParametricRegion((r, t, p), (r, 0, oo), (t, 0,pi), (p,0,2*pi))
volelem=SPH.R**2 * sin(SPH.T)
vector_integrate(volelem*f, R3).simplify()
```

The result is `8 pi / a**3`.
But with the double integral, I don't know how to tell sympy the integration bounds. All I tried led to errors. One attempt was

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, ParametricRegion, vector_integrate
a,r1,t1,p1,r2,t2,p2 = symbols('a,r1,t1,p1,r2,t2,p2')
SPH1=CoordSys3D('1', transformation='spherical', vector_names=list('rtp'), variable_names=list('RTP'))
SPH2=CoordSys3D('2', transformation='spherical', vector_names=list('rtp'), variable_names=list('RTP'))
f = exp(-a*SPH1.R-a*SPH2.R)
R6 = ParametricRegion((r1, t1, p1,r2, t2, p2), (r1, 0, 1), (t1, 0,pi), (p1,0,2*pi),(r2, 0, 1), (t2, 0,pi), (p2,0,2*pi))
volelem=SPH1.R**2 * sin(SPH1.T) * SPH2.R**2 * sin(SPH2.T)
vector_integrate(volelem*f, R6)
```

which led to

```
ValueError
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f2fa9aaffc5f> in <module>
      7 R6 = ParametricRegion((r1, t1, p1,r2, t2, p2), (r1, 0, 1), (t1, 0,pi), (p1,0,2*pi),(r2, 0, 1), (t2, 0,pi), (p2,0,2*pi))
      8 volelem=SPH1.R**2 * sin(SPH1.T) * SPH2.R**2 * sin(SPH2.T)
----> 9 vector_integrate(volelem*f, R6)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/vector/integrals.py in vector_integrate(field, *region)
    191     if len(region) == 1:
    192         if isinstance(region[0], ParametricRegion):
--> 193             return ParametricIntegral(field, region[0])
    194 
    195         if isinstance(region[0], ImplicitRegion):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/vector/integrals.py in __new__(cls, field, parametricregion)
     46             coord_sys = CoordSys3D('C')
     47         elif len(coord_set) > 1:
---> 48             raise ValueError
     49         else:
     50             coord_sys = next(iter(coord_set))

ValueError:
```

I know this integral is easy. I chose this formula for simplicity. My application is another function `f` which is not of product form.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Might be better to ask on the SymPy mailing list rather than here.

Comment: Of course you can always just write these out as ordinary integrals.